# System Versioning time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am in EST zone. My server is local on my computer. But the time SQL Server enters for the StartTime Generated Always as Row Start is 4 hours later. 
This is the code:
'''

```
    create Table TemTable(
    ID int identity(1,1) not null primary key, 
    name varchar(40), 
    sysStartTime datetime2 generated always as row Start,
    sysEndTime datetime2 generated always as row End,
    Period for System_time(sysStartTime,sysEndTime)) 
    With (system_versioning = on (History_table = dbo.TemTableHistory))
    declare @i int = 1;

while (@i<10)
    Begin
        insert into TemTable(name) values ('Person-' + cast(@i as varchar(2)))
        set @i = @i + 1
    End
```

'''

When my local time is 13:10:10 the SysStartTime is 17:10:10
GetDate(), SysDateTime(), current_TimeStamp all show the local time correctly.

Comment: That does not look like valid T-SQL. At a guess, you're using `SYSUTCDATETIME()` *somewhere*.

Comment: Also, on a different note, `17:10:10` isn't 4 hours after `01:10:10`, it's 16 hours after; which implies a different problem.

Comment: This looks like postgres, not sql server. What DBMS are you actually using?

Comment: I am using T-SQL. Server 2019. What about this does not look like T-SQL?

Comment: Ahh yes...temporal tables. I don't work with them all the time and wasn't making the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that SQL Server save UTC as system versioning time.